# Capitalize string and return local variable

Tags: c, string

I'm trying to make a procedure that will capitalize a string, but I get junk values and a warning from gcc that I'm returning the address of a local variable. Coming from Python, I'm confused by this issue. (Don't want to use stuff in `<string.h>`)

```
 2
 3
 4char* strcaps(const char *strlower)
 5{
 6  int len = 0;
 7  while (*strlower != '\0'){
 8    len++;
 9    strlower++;
10  }
11  char newStr[len + 1];
12  int i;
13  for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
14    newStr[i] = strlower[i] - 32;
    newStr[len + 1] = '\0';    //EDIT, just put this in.
15  return newStr;
16}
17
18int main(void)
19{
20  
21  
22  
23  printf("I expect capitalized version of edgar, I got %s\n", strcaps("edgar"));
24
25
26  return 0;
27}
```

I'm guessing I can make a global string and then mutable that, but I'd rather keep everything inside the function strcaps...is this a case when I should use malloc?

Thanks

EDIT: Just realized that I never put a `'\0`' at the end of the new string, although I'm not sure if that is related.

Comment: It is related too, but, as the compiler warning says, you are not supposed to return a pointer to a local (non-`static`) variable. When the function returns, it vanishes, and you will get back a pointer that doesn't point to anything meaningful. You will have to use `malloc()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options in C.

1) you can pass your function an pointer to the string and function will modify it and return void

In this case you can just use the original string

2) you can pass your function `const char*` and return `char *`, but then you need to malloc inside the function

If you do a malloc inside function, you can then use the string (print it or do whatever you want), at the and of the program you call `free`

Comment: Say I do `malloc`, I'm just using it as a value for printf, what will happen to that memory? Since I'm not calling `free` anywhere, will it leak memory? And how could I fix that considering that I'm making the string just inside the procedure `strcaps`

Comment: just `free` it after using printf

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian if you malloc it, you need to free it too (or leak memory). So you need a temp variable. This demonstrates how C is a pretty low level language. No objects with automatic destructors, no garbage collection, but no "invisible" overhead either.

Answer (score 1):

> is this a case when I should use malloc?

Yes, exactly.

In your case, you return pointer to local variable, which (the variable) will be destroyed after the execution of the function. This makes the pointer dangling.

Using `malloc` will create the string in the heap, not stack, and it will remain valid after after the return of the function.

Comment: Say I do `malloc`, I'm just using it as a value for `printf`, what will happen to that memory? Since I'm not calling free anywhere, will it leak memory? And how could I fix that considering that I'm making the string just inside the procedure `strcaps`

Comment: Yes, it will leak. Well, you're creating the string inside the function, but you're trying to use it outside the funciton and that's the issue here. One way is to store the result in pointer, print it and `free` it. Or print it inside the function and do not return anything.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should always put a null character at the end of a string, because the standard library uses this to denote the actual end of a string, to prevent from walking over memory.

This is an implementation.

```
/* Makes a copy of the string as to not modify the original buffer */
char* makeCopy(char* s){

    char* buff = (char*) malloc(len(s) + 1);
    strcpy(buff, s);
    return buff;
}

/* Converts the string to uppercase */
char* toUpperCase(char* s){

        char* q = makeCopy(s);
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < len(q); i++){
                *(q + i) = toupper(*(q + i));
        }

        return q;

}
```

Now you can do:

```
printf("I expect capitalized version of edgar, I got %s\n", toUpperCase("edgar"));
```

Now I understand that you don't want to touch any of the stuff in `string.h`, but it is useful, for without the functions there you may need to implement much of the stuff on your own.

For example, the function `toupper()` comes from `string.h`. This converts a character to its uppercase equivalent. If you insist on reinventing the wheel you can hack a tiny function that handles it.

```
char getUpperCaseChar(char lower){
    if(lower < 91)
        return lower;
    if(lower > 96)
        return (lower - 32);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for a way to keep it all in one function. I'm not understanding the need for a buffer.

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian I use buffers just so if I need to keep the original string for some reason, I still have access to it.