# Not returning string. This program converts digit like 123 to words like "One Two Three", why in the end I am not getting anything?

Tags: c, function, recursion, strcat

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

char *int_to_string( int n );

void main()
{
    int n;

    printf("Enter the number : ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    printf("\n%d in words is : %s.\n",n,int_to_string(n));
}

char *int_to_string( int n)
{
    char str[100]="";

    if(n<10)
    {
          switch(n)
        {
            case 0: return "Zero";
            case 1: return "One";
            case 2: return "Two";
            case 3: return "Three";
            case 4: return "Four";
            case 5: return "Five";
            case 6: return "Six";
            case 7: return "Seven";
            case 8: return "Eight";
            case 9: return "Nine";
        }
    }

    else
    {
        strcat(str,int_to_string(n/10));
        strcat(str," ");

        return strcat(str,int_to_string(n%10));
    }
}
```

Function int_to_string() should return a string containing equivalent of the number in words that is passed. it works fine for single digit number ( i.e. 0-9 ) but above that it just gives nothing.

Comment: Fyi, your program invokes *undefined behavior*. `str[]` no longer exists once `int_to_string` returns. [Read this. Seriously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope/6445794#6445794).

Comment: or, you know, the base case of the recursion (n < 10) doesn't return anything, so if it ever got to the "bottom" it wouldn't return anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capitalize string and return local variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20292800/capitalize-string-and-return-local-variable)

Comment: Even if fixing the local variable issue, your recursion is logically suspect, and wouldn't work as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function has undefined behaviour.

It returns a pointer to local array `str` that is in general destroyed after exiting the function.

Take into account that it is better to define the parameter as having type `unsigned int`. Otherwise the function needs to check whether the number is not negative.

You could make the task easier by means of declaring second parameter that will specify a character zero-terminated array that will store the result string.

Or you have to allocate memory dynamically.

Here are shown these two approaches.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char * int_to_string( unsigned int n )
{
    if( n < 10 )
    {
        char *p = "";

        switch( n )
        {
        case 0: 
            p = "Zero";
            break;
        case 1: 
            p = "One";
            break;
        case 2: 
            p = "Two";
            break;
        case 3: 
            p = "Three";
            break;
        case 4: 
            p = "Four";
            break;
        case 5: 
            p = "Five";
            break;
        case 6: 
            p = "Six";
            break;
        case 7: 
            p = "Seven";
            break;
        case 8: 
            p = "Eight";
            break;
        case 9: 
            p = "Nine";
            break;
        }
        char *q = malloc( strlen( p ) + 1 );
        strcpy( q, p );
        free( p );
        return q; 
    }
    else
    {
        char *q = int_to_string( n / 10 );
        char *p = int_to_string( n % 10 );

        q = realloc( q, strlen( q ) + strlen( p ) + 2 );
        strcat( q, " " );
        return strcat( q, p );
    }
}

char * int_to_string1( unsigned int n, char *s )
{
    if( n < 10 )
    {
        char *p = "";

        switch( n )
        {
        case 0: 
            p = "Zero";
            break;
        case 1: 
            p = "One";
            break;
        case 2: 
            p = "Two";
            break;
        case 3: 
            p = "Three";
            break;
        case 4: 
            p = "Four";
            break;
        case 5: 
            p = "Five";
            break;
        case 6: 
            p = "Six";
            break;
        case 7: 
            p = "Seven";
            break;
        case 8: 
            p = "Eight";
            break;
        case 9: 
            p = "Nine";
            break;
        }

        return strcat( s, p );
    }
    else
    {
        strcat( int_to_string1( n / 10, s ), " " );

        return int_to_string1( n % 10, s );
    }
}

int main( void )
{
    unsigned int n = 1234567890;
    char *s = int_to_string( n );

    puts( s );

    free( s );

    char s1[100];
    s1[0] = '\0';

    puts( int_to_string1( n, s1 ) );
}
```

The program output is

```
One Two Three Four Five Six Seven Eight Nine Zero
One Two Three Four Five Six Seven Eight Nine Zero
```

Comment: it returns a string equivalent to number for n<10. e.g. for **int_to_string(5)** returns "**Five**" @marshall

Comment: Vlad for `n < 10` please [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267114/scope-of-string-literals)

Answer (score 2):

Please use string copy before sending a final string. Add last two line in your code it'll work.

```
    char *int_to_string( int n)
    {
       char str[100]="";
       char str1[100]="";//
       .
       .
       .
       strcat(str,int_to_string(n/10));
       strcat(str," ");     
       strcat(str,int_to_string(n%10));
       strcpy(str1,str);//create one more str1 array of 100 and copy final data
       return str1;// return str1 array of data
     }
```

Comment: `str1` is still an automatic/local variable which will be popped off the stack when `int_to_string` returns.

Answer (score 1):

1)

In your function `str` as an automatic variable on the stack was destroyed after the `int_to_string` returned. But you need `str` to be alive for more `int_to_string` calls! So you have to preserve `str` between calls.

2)

```
case 0: return "Zero";
....
```

The code above will not work properly in recursion calls, the word "Zero" has to be added to `str` string

```
     case 0: strcat(str,"Zero"); return str;
```

But why suffer with recursion calls? Recursion can be replaced with a simple loop. Both solutions are shown.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

void print_digit(int digit)
{
    switch(digit)
    {
        case '0': printf("Zero "); break;
        case '1': printf("One ");  break;
        case '2': printf("Two ");  break;
        case '3': printf("Three ");break;
        case '4': printf("Four "); break;
        case '5': printf("Five "); break;
        case '6': printf("Six ");  break;
        case '7': printf("Seven ");break;
        case '8': printf("Eight ");break;
        case '9': printf("Nine "); break;
   }
}

char * return_digit_word(int digit)
{
    switch(digit)
    {
        case '0': return("Zero "); break;
        case '1': return("One ");  break;
        case '2': return("Two ");  break;
        case '3': return("Three ");break;
        case '4': return("Four "); break;
        case '5': return("Five "); break;
        case '6': return("Six ");  break;
        case '7': return("Seven ");break;
        case '8': return("Eight ");break;
        case '9': return("Nine "); break;
   }
}

char *int_to_string(int n,char str[],char numStr[]) 
{
     if(n<10)
     {
        switch(n)
        {
            case 0: strcat(str,"Zero");break;
            case 1: strcat(str,"One");break;
            case 2: strcat(str,"Two");break;
            case 3: strcat(str,"Three");break;
            case 4: strcat(str,"Four");break;
            case 5: strcat(str,"Five");break;
            case 6: strcat(str,"Six");break;
            case 7: strcat(str,"Seven");break;
            case 8: strcat(str,"Eight");break;
            case 9: strcat(str,"Nine");break;
        }
        return str;
    }
    else{
        int digit = numStr[0]-'0';
        int newNr =  n - digit*pow(10,strlen(numStr)-1);        

        strcat(str, return_digit_word(numStr[0]));
        sprintf(numStr, "%d", newNr); 

        return int_to_string(newNr,str,numStr);
    }
} 


int main(void) {
    int n,i;
    char str[100]="";
    char numStr[100]="";

    n = 1234567890;

    sprintf(numStr, "%d", n);
    printf("\n%d in words is : %s\n",n, int_to_string(n,str,numStr) );

    printf("\n%d in words is : ",n);
    sprintf(numStr, "%d", n);
    for(i=0;i<strlen(numStr);i++)
    {
       print_digit(numStr[i]);
    }

   return 0;
}
```

Output for n=1234567890:

```
1234567890 in words is : One Two Three Four Five Six Seven Eight Nine Zero

1234567890 in words is : One Two Three Four Five Six Seven Eight Nine Zero
```

Comment: @user3078414  Thanks! I know it. The point was to preserve `str`. I did not debug the logic of the function. Personally, I would use a simple loop as presented.

Comment: I wouldn't use recursion at all, but that's not the point - nobody cares if "you know it", or if original code has to be "debugged for logic". If you can give a simple, clear and universally useful answer retaining as much of original code as meaningful, than do it. Else, think twice before posting answers, IMHO.

Comment: @user3078414 Sorry, I cannot debug the logic of this program. I pointed out the problem with automatic variable. I presented the alternative solution. That is all what I can do ATM. I appreciate your point of view. Thank you for your input.

Comment: @user3078414 FYI I have also presented solution with working recursion.